# OpenShift: Tomcat 7: Cron suddenly stopped working three days ago

Tags: cron, openshift

I had one script running under the .openshift/cron/daily like a clockwork, but suddenly, three days ago, it stopped working, without my intervention.

I created a simple script with a "echo Hello" under the .openshift/cron/minutely, I grant execute permissions (just in case), and I pushed it.

Nothing! The scripts never trigger.

I also tried restarting the Cron 1.4 cartridge, but nothing happened.

I have a Tomcat 7 (JBoss EWS 2.0) cartridge, a PostgreSQL 9.2, and the Cron 1.4 embedded.

Any ideas?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue should be fixed now.  Please open a request at help.openshift.com if you continue to have issues with it.